# Неправильное отображение Версии Windows

Tags: c#

Всем привет.
Работаю с Visual Studio 2012 и на Windows 10.

Написал программу которая выводит версию Windows `System.Environment.OSVersion.Version`. Но при запуске выдает, что я работаю на Windows 8. Порылся по гуглу и понял, что нужно добавить в манифест строчку кода `<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>`, добавил, результат тот же, мне отображает, что я работаю с Windows 8.

Собрал все в msi файл и попробовал запустить на другом компьютере с Windows 10 где нет Visual Studio, а вдруг, но эффект был тот же, Windows 8.

Что я делаю не так? Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что выдаёт `System.Environment.OSVersion.VersionString`?

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать функцию два раза подряд. Несколько раз помогало. При чем в утекших некогда исходниках Windows в комментариях к коду сами разработчики Microsoft очень удивлялись сему факту.

Comment: @VladD Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич открываб 2 разных проекта в одном показывает Windows 10 в другом Windows 8, хотя файлы манифеста одинаковые, как так?

Comment: @OuFinx: Хм, и правда. А может, вы добавляете не в тот манифест? Например, в манифест библиотеки, а не приложения?

Comment: @VladD да нет, в тот же :)

Comment: Перекомпилируйтесь, перезапустите Студию. Должно работать по идее.

Comment: @VladD удивительно, но это помогло, хотя я десятки раз до этого перезаходил.

Comment: @OuFinx привыкайте. Это Windows. Cамое не приятное, что этот баг потом у заказчика может выскочить.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич: На линуксе, думаете, проблем нет?

Comment: @OuFinx: Значит, что-то не сделали. Чудес ведь не бывает. Но хорошо, что сейчас сработало.

Answer (score 0):

Прописывание секции compatibility — правильный путь. Согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx), `Environment.OSVersion` возвращает версию согласно WinAPI-функции `GetVersionEx`. [Эта функция](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx), в свою очередь, возвращает версию 8.0, если не установлен нужный манифест:

> Applications not manifested for Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 will return the Windows 8 OS version value (6.2). Once an application is manifested for a given operating system version, `GetVersionEx` will always return the version that the application is manifested for in future releases.

---

Это значит, что вы сделали всё правильно, и где-то у Visual Studio осталась закешированной старая версия исполняемого файла или манифеста. Выглядит как мелкий баг Visual Studio.

Перестройте программу по новой, перезапустите Visual Studio, проблема должна исчезнуть.